# PDFTron: Powerpoint ConverToXod not working

Tags: c#, powerpoint, pdftron, pdfnet

In my ASP .Net application, I am using 'PDFTron 6.6.0.38591'. 
We are using following code to convert Office documents to XOD:

```
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pdfTronServiceRequest.FilePath);
                fileName = ConstructConvertionFileName(fileName);
                outFileName = Path.Combine(outputPath, fileName);
                pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXod(pdfTronServiceRequest.FilePath, outFileName);    
                response.Result = outFileName;
```

This code works well for filetypes like docx, xlsx, however for Powerpoint files, no response is returned(request timed out).
On checking the Task Manager window, we can see that a process for 'POWERPNT.exe' is started. However, this process never ends up itself(unlike that in case of word, excel upload).
Also, if I manually ends up this process, the conversion to XOD is successful and response is coming out correctly.

Also, please note that we are facing this issue only when we deploy the code on our test environments. Locally, PPT upload is working fine.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be running a licensed version of PowerPoint, not a trial/eval one. In particular, the account (including a Service/App Pool account) needs to have accepted the MS office licensing to make sure Office is a fully licensed product.

Also, is this happening with any ppt file or only certain ones? If certain ones, then try using one of the following two flags.

pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.[SetMode](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/M_pdftron_PDF_Convert_Printer_SetMode.htm)([mode](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/T_pdftron_PDF_Convert_Printer_Mode.htm))

```
e_printer_only
e_interop_only
```

Finally, switch to the [latest version](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html). Which at the very least should provide a lot more debugging info in the exception message.

Comment: I will surely give these suggestions a try! We are using Trial version of MS Office 2013 at our test environment, where PDFTron is failing for PPT Upload. 
Just wondering, why it is failing only for .ppt Upload, but not for other types like .docx, .xlsx etc. Please explain.